# Does memory handling violate the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: c++, memory, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, pointers

```
SRP : There should never be more than one reason for a class to change
```

If I have a `class A` whose responsibility is performing `taskA`. Does the memory handling inside `class A` violate the SRP?  If so, Is it acceptable? What solutions do we have?

Note: Using `delete` or `a std smart_ptr` is the same, it is still a sort of memory handling (e.g. : We might want to change unique_ptr auto_ptr, etc...).

Here is how I thought one could deal with it. I don't find it good enough because MemoryHandler has to change for two reasons: if A needs more attributes or if we want another way of handling memory.

Note about the examples: Normally you would have a lot of methods (member functions) and multiple attributes (member variables).
We may suppose owned_ptr is a functor (an algorithm / pattern strategy) or anything else needed by `class A` and `task A`.

Example 1 (cpp):

```
class A {
   Object* owned_ptr;

public:
   taskA() { ... }
   ~A() { delete owned_ptr; }
};
```

Example 2 (cpp):

```
class MemoryHandler {
   Object* owned_ptr;
public :
   Object* object() { return owned_ptr; }
   ~MemoryHandler() { delete owned_ptr; }
};

class A {
   MemoryHandler data;

public:
   taskA() { ... }
   ~A() { }
};
```

Comment: Does `taskA` use `owned_ptr`?

Comment: Yes, We may suppose it does (I edited the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pragmatically, the memory handling in your example does not violate the SRP. You're following a standard approach to memory handling in your environment, which is not really adding a separate responsibility. You wouldn't say, for example, that instantiating objects was a separate responsibility, and your case isn't all that different.

(If you'd written your own allocator and your class was full of both low-level memory-management code and higher-level domain code, that would be a different story.)

Comment: Well I do think that instantiating object is a reponsability ... I think that a class should not instanciate the objects it uses but ask for them : this allows dependency inversion.